# android, the test is failing caused by emoji button on the soft keyboard

Tags: android-espresso, android-softkeyboard, emoji

Having an espresso test that will type in the editView.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/displayNameEditText"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:hint="@string/display_name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="20sp" />



      try {
            onView(withId(R.id.displayNameEditText)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
            Log.d("+++"", "+++ === OK with onView(withText(R.id.displayNameEditText)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed())); ");

            //view is displayed logic
        } catch (NoMatchingViewException e) {
            Log.d("+++", "+++ === !!! exception in onView(withText(R.id.displayNameEditText)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed())); "+e);
        }

        Log.d(B"+++", "+++ === call onView(withId(R.id.displayNameEditText)).perform(clearText(), typeText(displayName)); in " + TAG);

        onView(withId(R.id.displayNameEditText)).perform(clearText(), typeText(displayName));
```

When type in the first field it is fine:

[image]

When try to typein the second editView (`R.id.displayNameEditText`), it failed.
But the log shows that the editView is displayed (not seeing the exception log).

Noticed when it focuses on the `Display Name` field, there is a floating tooltip [image] showing up on top of emoji icon on the keyboard.
Then the `onView(withId(R.id.displayNameEditText)).perform(clearText(), typeText(displayName));` failed.

So wondering how to force not showing this floating tooltip? or showing the keyboard with character/number only?

By the way the device is a Android 8.0.0    Samsung Galaxy S9 device.

```
{"level":"DEBUG","processId":24557,"tag":"+++","message":"+++ : +++ === OK with onView(withText(R.id.displayNameEditText)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));","timestamp":"2023-09-21 11:08:58.410"}
{"level":"DEBUG","processId":24557,"tag":"+++","message":"+++ : +++ === call onView(withId(R.id.displayNameEditText)).perform(clearText(), typeText(displayName)); in SubscriptionPage","timestamp":"2023-09-21 11:08:58.410"}
{"level":"INFO","processId":24557,"tag":"ViewInteraction","message":"ViewInteraction : Performing 'replace text()' action on view view.getId() is <2131296451/com.test.com.demo:id/displayNameEditText>","timestamp":"2023-09-21 11:08:58.416"}
{"level":"WARN","processId":24557,"tag":".com.demo","message":".com.demo : Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)","timestamp":"2023-09-21 11:08:58.422"}
{"level":"INFO","processId":24557,"tag":"ViewInteraction","message":"ViewInteraction : Performing 'type text(test_display_name)' action on view view.getId() is <2131296451/com.test.com.demo:id/displayNameEditText>","timestamp":"2023-09-21 11:08:58.426"}
{"level":"DEBUG","processId":1466,"tag":"InputDispatcher","message":"InputDispatcher : Inject motion (24557): action=0x0, time=1738249000000, f=0x0, d=0","timestamp":"2023-09-21 11:08:58.428"}
{"level":"WARN","processId":1466,"tag":"InputDispatcher","message":"InputDispatcher : Permission denied: injecting event from pid 24557 uid 10261 to window Window{ec2bf75 u0 PopupWindow:482f751} owned by uid 10227","timestamp":"2023-09-21 11:08:58.428"}
{"level":"WARN","processId":1466,"tag":"InputManager","message":"InputManager : Input event injection from pid 24557 permission denied.","timestamp":"2023-09-21 11:08:58.430"}
{"level":"WARN","processId":24557,"tag":"EventInjectionStrategy","message":"EventInjectionStrategy : Error performing a ViewAction! soft keyboard dismissal animation may have been in the way. Retrying once after: 1000 millis","timestamp":"2023-09-21 11:08:58.433"}
{"level":"ERROR","processId":898,"tag":"NativeSemDvfsGpuManager","message":"NativeSemDvfsGpuManager : acquire:: Start","timestamp":"2023-09-21 11:08:58.440"}
{"level":"ERROR","processId":898,"tag":"NativeSemDvfsGpuManager","message":"NativeSemDvfsGpuManager : acquire:: timeout = 1000 mIsAcquired = 1  mTagName : SurfaceFlinger","timestamp":"2023-09-21 11:08:58.441"}
{"level":"ERROR","processId":898,"tag":"NativeCustomFrequencyManager","message":"NativeCustomFrequencyManager : [NativeCFMS] BpCustomFrequencyManager::requestGPU()","timestamp":"2023-09-21 11:08:58.441"}
{"level":"ERROR","processId":898,"tag":"NativeSemDvfsGpuManager","message":"NativeSemDvfsGpuManager : acquire:: End","timestamp":"2023-09-21 11:08:58.441"}
```

[image]